# UML -differences between drawn ports in the interfaces

Tags: uml

I can't find what are the differences between the ports on these interfaces. What's the difference in action?

[image]

Comment: What's you concern? The icons inside the ports?

Comment: I have scanned the UML 2.5 spec and it does not have that notation. So it's likely part of some profile. Whithout knowing that your question can not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols in the ports (squares) are obviously customer specific. The rest is an excerpt of a composite structure diagram. Four simple ports are shown, that offer (ball symbol) or use (socket symbol) a certain interface. So far so good. However, the connectors cannot connect the interface symbols (the balls and sockets). They must connect the ports (the squares). For simple ports (i.e. offering or using only one interface) it is an option to show the ball and socket symbol on the connector, as is done here. Another option is to show the connector connected to the interface symbols. In this case, there would be no ball and socket symbol on the connector. These are three visualizations of the same model. I usually only use a normal line between ports.